# word to describe a quote often attributed to but not verified to a person

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, vocabulary

I have seen this word many times but can't for the life of me able to remember. The word refers to a quote which is often attributed to someone but no one can verify whether the person actually said so.

Let me give an example. Einstein (that word) "Everybody is a genius. But if you judge a fish by its ability to climb a tre......"

It is very likely that I am getting it mixed up. I am not quite sure I am looking for the word **aphorism**

Please kindly help !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word you are looking for is **[apocryphal](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/apocryphal)**.

> *adjective* (of a story or statement) of doubtful authenticity, although widely circulated as being true: *an apocryphal story about a former president*

Comment: I agree that's probably the word he's after, but it doesn't fit in the slot he's provided. What fits in the slot is: "*is purported to have said*"

Comment: Thanks very much. I agree it does not fit in the slot.

Comment: @Jim No, it doesn't fit in the slot. But neither does _aphorism_. I was merely replacing the suggested word with the word I _know_ he or she is actually seeking, given the state of his or her language skill. To fit something into the slot, however, we _might_ suggest merely "said," and then the quote would be followed by the word "apocryphal" (sans quotation marks) placed in parentheses, thus: Einstein said, "Everybody..." (apocryphal). I believe this would be the generally accepted usage, although I have seen "Einstein apocryphally said." (I cringe at this, and do not recommend it.)

Comment: @Jim I suppose, to be fair, I might also suggest _allegedly_, as in "Einstein allegedly said," and _purportedly_, and "It is _attributed_ to Einstein," and "one of Einstein's _dicta_ (or _dictums_) is" -- but none of these exactly fits the slot, _n'est pas_? I still think _apocryphal_ is the target word.